# Take the name attribute of an option element and put it into a php variable

Tags: php, html, ajax, forms, post

So I have an HTML dropdown that is created in php.

```
echo '<select id="myselect" name="myselect">';

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        echo '<option value="'.$row['categories'].'" id="'.$row['categories'].'">'.$row['categories'].'</option>';
    }

    echo '</select>';
```

What I want to do is take the selected option and turn it into a variable so I can pass it to another php page.

Comment: Suggested keywords "post", "php form", and "ajax"

Comment: Not sure why this is being downvoted. It's a real question, just one that has a poor understanding of how server side scripting works

Comment: I think what he's trying to ask is: when the form is submitted, he only gets the selected option's value, and not what's visible in the dropdown -- how can he get what's visible in the dropdown? This is a perfectly valid question, just poorly worded.

Comment: @Mala yes sorry about the wording.  I was a little confused with how to word it.  Thanks

Comment: @dtoebe nothing wrong with that. we were all there once

Answer (score 2):

```
echo '<select id="myselect" name="myselect">';
    echo '<option value="make_selection" id="make_selection" name="make_selection">Choose Your Category</option>';

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        echo '<option value="'.$row['categories'].'" id="'.$row['categories'].'">'.$row['categories'].'</option>';
    }

    echo '</select>';
```

Above that:

```
if($_POST){
    $selection = $_POST['make_selection'];
    //do something with $selection
    //possibly redirect user using header('Location: page.php');
}
```

Comment: That will work for the 'make_selection' but that is "static" in the php I should have never included that line.  Thanks

Comment: What about the selected item (option)? Can you directly assign it to the `$selection` variable in this way?

Answer (score 1):

Just for your own knowledge, this isn't how php works. Once this script is ran, it displays on the users browser, and you won't be able to do anything else without them submitting the form, or sending an ajax request.

Comment: ok so put it into a javascript variable then post it to the second php page?

Comment: that is one way you can do it :-) This page may be helpful to you: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: Thanks I will use that and figure it out then reword my question and answer it so is more useful. I was hoping there was a way to do it in php without ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP runs on the server. The resulting HTML/JavaScript is viewed by the user in their browser on their client PC. You need to communicate between the two over HTTP (e.g. via Ajax/JavaScript or with a full round-trip to the server). Simply send a request when the dropdown's value changes.

An answer that's any more specific would require an equivalently specific question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the selected option to be passed to the next PHP page, you have to also assign a `name` attribute on the `option`.

```
echo '<select id="myselect" name="myselect">';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    echo '<option name="option[]" value="'.$row['categories'].'" id="'.$row['categories'].'">'.$row['categories'].'</option>';
    $i++;
}

echo '</select>';
```

Then on the receiving page:

```
if(isset($_POST['option'])) {
    // process here
    print_r($_POST['option']);
}
```

The `[]` means PHP will see all of the options as values in an array, therefore they can be iterated over.

Also, I would suggest using [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php), it stands for MySQL Improved.